# mysqldump space in directory with variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command, quotes

I have a batch file that mysqlpdump into a directory share folder that has a space in the dir name.

```
@echo off
set datefix=%DATE%
set datefix=%DATE:/=-%

mysqldump -u -p mydb > C:\Weird Dir\backup\%datefix%.sql
exit
```

Creates this error:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "Dir\backup\06-25-13.sql"
```

I've tried googling for the syntax of using a directory name but can't find anything.  Tried setting full path as variable and then including and concat the string but it gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mysqldump -u -p mydb > "C:\Weird Dir\backup\%datefix%.sql"
```

put the whole path in double quotes.

Comment: DOUBLE QUOTES. Ugh. Was using single. Thanks.  "I don't write batch files often. But when I do, I use improper syntax."

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
mysqldump -u -p mydb > "C:\Weird Dir\backup\"%datefix%.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump -u -p mydb > "C:\Weird Dir\backup\%datefix%.sql"`